# Find cause for error 429 (throttling) in Azure portal

Tags: azure, throttling, http-status-code-429

We have a problem with the Azure Portal for a specific tenant. It shows the following error message as if there were more than 12k requests to the portal. We make like 15k requests but to the Cosmos DB. Something new we did was to create an Azure Container Registry and 5 containers in the Resource Group that have FFmpeg running and streaming. Any clues about how to find the origin of this error?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GGuNQe7.png]

> Number of tenant-level requests exceeded the limit of '12000' for time
> interval '01:00:00'. Please try again after '300' seconds. (Code:
> TenantRequestsThrottled)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling

Comment: You can view which collection is returning 429's in the Azure Portal. Just go to your CosmosDB, click on "Metrics" then find the "Throughput" tab. You can (maybe) alleviate these 429's by increasing the RU/s on the specific collection that is throwing the 429s. Just be forewarned: CosmosDB can get expensive.

Comment: @Andy Did what you said but the Cosmos DB shows no 429 requests.

Comment: @Sajeetharan That was useful to know about the limits, but useless about how to find what is exceeding that limit, something that remains as a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

You receive the HTTP status code 429 Too many requests. The response includes a Retry-After value, which specifies the number of seconds your application should wait (or sleep) before sending the next request. If you send a request before the retry value has elapsed, your request isn't processed and a new retry value is returned.

Please follow the link for solution: [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling)

Comment: That article explains what are the limits and how to know the remaining quota, however it does not explain how to find what is exceeding that limit and causing the error 